# Binding behaviors from viewmodel in listview in xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms, behavior

I have a list view which I am using to display a form.
Here is my item source:

```
ObservableCollection<ContactBlockFieldViewModel> ContactBlockFIelds
```

Each ContactBlockFieldViewModel contains `public EContactFieldTypeDTO ContactField { get; set; }`

I want to bind the listview entry behavior property to specific behavior, depending on what type of contact field it is.

For example, for email type I would want my custom EmailValidationBehavior.

How can I accomplish this? I tried putting the behavior right in the viewmodel and then

```
                                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ContactBlockFields}" x:Name="ContactFieldsList">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding FormDisplayName}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"></Label>
                                    <Entry Text="{Binding Value}" BackgroundColor="{Binding BackgroundColor}">
                                        <Entry.Behaviors>
                                            <Binding Path="BehaviorInViewModel"></Binding>
                                        </Entry.Behaviors>
                                    </Entry>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

But it didn't work, I also tried to use a converter which would convert the enum to Behavior but also without success. I checked in debug and the constructor of the behavior gets called, but the object is not being bound.

Comment: The `Behaviors` property is of type `IList<Behavior>`. Did you try to bind it to a `List<Behavior>` in the viewmodel? Also since behaviors is a UI related thing I would not put these in the viewmodel from an architectural point of view.

Comment: I did try to use List<Behavior> too, but it didn't change anything. Yes, I would prefer not to put them there, I tried to create a converter which would return a behavior based on the enum type (and i tried to return behavior and a list of behaviors) - the behavior object got created, but it didn't work.

Comment: Alternatively what you could also do is add all possible for the element behaviors in XAML and create a boolean BindableProperty in them which enables/disables the behavior. I have yet to see someone bind an entire collection of behaviors so I'm doubtful if it's even possible.